# The meaning of "were to" in the remote conditional

Tags: conditionals

CGEL* (Page 753) says

> [46] i a. #*If it is to rain, I’ll cancel the show.* b. *If it were to rain, I’d cancel the show.*
>
> There is an idiomatic use of what we call ‘quasi-modal ***be***’ that occurs only in remote conditionals like [ib]. In the open conditional ***If we are to survive we’ll have to drastically reduce expenditure*** the protasis suggests purpose (“In order to survive, we’ll have to drastically reduce expenditure”), which is why [ia] is pragmatically anomalous. In the remote conditional, this quasi-modal ***be*** serves merely to reinforce the remote meaning: the protasis of [ib] means “if it rained” but with a slightly stronger implicature of unlikelihood. It occurs predominantly in future time protases.

Here, CGEL seems to say that ***were to*** in the remote conditional doesn't have the same meaning of "purpose" as does "am/is/are to" in the open conditional. But the open conditional example above has this corresponding remote conditional:

> ***If we were to survive we’d have to drastically reduce expenditure***

Now, doesn't this suggest purpose (“In order to survive, we’d have to drastically reduce expenditure”) just like its open conditional counterpart?

If it does, is CGEL's claim "In the remote conditional, this quasi-modal be serves merely to reinforce the remote meaning" still valid?

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language

Comment: I don't read it as "in order to survive."  I read it as "if it turns out that we do survive"

Comment: @Jim Which are you talking about? "If we are to survive" or "If we were to survive"?

Comment: If we were to survive...

Comment: @Jim Then, you must think _If we were to survive we’d have to drastically reduce expenditure_ doesn't make sense or at least doesn't represent the remote version of _If we are to survive we’ll have to drastically reduce expenditure_.

Comment: I read it with emphasis in *were*.  The context I envision is that a group of people are running through their money at a terrific rate but because they believe they won't survive, it really doesn't matter.   When someone asks, "What if we do survive?"  This is the answer.  In other words, if we do end up surviving this, we won't be able to continue to spend at our current rate, we'll have to drastically reduce our expenditures.

Comment: @Jim I think that's a very contrived reading, even though it can be read that way.  I'm curious why you would "envision" the context in such a contrived way. I'm sure there are enough examples out there that would allow it to be construed as "in order to survive" as in this New Yorker article: _Eventually, Kumar decided that, if he and his crewmates were to survive, “we would have to fight.” They couldn’t force their way off the ship, but perhaps they could reason their way off, even if their captors were unreasonable._ https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/04/20/escape-or-die

Comment: Ah, that's a past tense, narrative context.  I was trying to put it in an active present context.

Comment: Correct me, and you seem to be suggesting there’s a difference between “If we are to…” and “In order to…” and further, even “If we were to survive…”

Fine but if so is it your job or ours to explain the differences and select the one preferred?

Comment: If CGEL really says “If it is to rain, I’ll cancel the show” then doubtless CGEL can justify that. D’you think anyone else can?

“If it were to rain, I’d cancel the show” is such a different construction, you’d have to go a very long way to justify any similarity.

I’m sorry to say that all the rest of your post seems, at best, pretentious rubbish.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't quite catch your drift, except that my post is rubbish AND pretentious, whatever the latter means. No wonder I don't understand the cited portion of CGEL, when I don't even understand your comments.

Comment: To me Jim’s not “in order to…” but “if it turns out that we do/turned out that we did…” seems so obvious, the only question would be why anyone doubted that.

Either way, I don’t understand how there could be a useful comparison between the phrases.

Isn’t it obvious *If we are to…* deals with what might help us to survive while 

*If we were to…* deals with what might follow from our survival?

More simply, are *survive* and *survival* semantically identical, or somewhat different?